How to get First timing & Last timing of the day through Looping
I have a list of Door entry timing with multiple date. So I am trying to find the first entry timing of the day and the last entry timing of the same day.
Column D & E is done being manually input. I wish to use VBA loop to do it.
By using the Normal excel function, i have tried using the function LARGE & SMALL to find the first and last timing of the day.
Example: LARGE(IF(A1 = A1:A100,ROW(A1:A100)),1) which would return me the Largest row then I use INDEX.

Therefore I am wondering if I can do the same or is there a simpler way to do it in VBA so I can get the result in Column D & E.
So Far this is how far i got:
Sub testing2()

Dim dateList As Range

newLR = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

dateList = Sheet3.Range("a1:a" & newLR).Value

For x = 1 To newLR
    If Sheet3.Cells(x, 1) = dateList Then
        Sheet3.Cells(x, 4) = 3
    End If
Next x



End Sub



Not sure why you want to do it with VBA if it can be easily done using a pivot table or a formula, if you have Excel 365:
=LET(
    dates,(A2:A30),
    times,(B2:B30),
    days, UNIQUE(dates),
    earliest, BYROW(days, LAMBDA(day, MIN(IF(dates=day, times)))),
    latest, BYROW(days, LAMBDA(day, MAX(IF(dates=day, times)))),
    result, HSTACK(days, earliest, latest),
    result
)

or in a slightly different way:
=LET(
    dates, A2:A30,
    times, B2:B30,
    days, UNIQUE(dates),
    earliest, MAP(days, LAMBDA(day, MINIFS(times, dates, day))),
    latest, MAP(days, LAMBDA(day, MAXIFS(times, dates, day))),
    HSTACK(days, earliest, latest)
)

or perhaps:
=LET(
    data, A2:B30,
    days, UNIQUE(INDEX(data,,1)),
    times, LAMBDA(day, FILTER(INDEX(data,,2), INDEX(data,,1)=day)),
    earliest, BYROW(days, LAMBDA(day, MIN(times(day)))),
    latest, BYROW(days, LAMBDA(day, MAX(times(day)))),
    HSTACK(days, earliest, latest)
)

or if you want it with two columns:
=LET(
    dates,(A2:A30),
    times,(B2:B30),
    days, UNIQUE(dates),
    earliest, BYROW(days, LAMBDA(day, MIN(IF(dates=day, times)))),
    latest, BYROW(days, LAMBDA(day, MAX(IF(dates=day, times)))),
    repeatedDays, VSTACK(days, days),
    inout, VSTACK(earliest, latest),
    result, HSTACK(repeatedDays, inout),
    result
)



Get the first and last timing for each day with two dictionary objects.
Microsoft documentation:

Range.CurrentRegion property (Excel)


Range.Resize property (Excel)

Sub Demo()
    Dim oDicMin As Object, oDicMax As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, vKey, vTmp
    Dim arrData
    Set oDicMin = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set oDicMax = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' load data into an array
    Set rngData = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ' loop through data
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        vKey = arrData(i, 1) ' Date (Col A) as the key
        vTmp = arrData(i, 2)
        If oDicMin.exists(vKey) Then
            If vTmp < oDicMin(vKey) Then
                oDicMin(vKey) = vTmp ' update Min
            End If
            If vTmp > oDicMax(vKey) Then
                oDicMax(vKey) = vTmp ' update Max
            End If
        Else ' Init. min and max
            oDicMin(vKey) = vTmp
            oDicMax(vKey) = vTmp
        End If
    Next i
    ' header of output
    Range("D1:F1").Value = Array("Date", "Min", "Max")
    Columns("E:F").NumberFormatLocal = "h:mm;@"
    Dim iCnt As Long
    iCnt = oDicMin.Count
    ' write output to sheet
    Range("D2").Resize(iCnt, 1) = Application.Transpose(oDicMin.keys)
    Range("E2").Resize(iCnt, 1) = Application.Transpose(oDicMin.items)
    Range("F2").Resize(iCnt, 1) = Application.Transpose(oDicMax.items)
End Sub


